# BitSet toString() and valueOf() are difficult to understand

Tags: java

I just want to convert integer to binary string using BitSet.

My code is below.

```
public class BitSetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Method_1
        int value = 10; //0b1010
        String bits = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(bits.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++) {
            if (bits.charAt(i) == '1') {
                bs.set(i);
            } else {
                bs.clear(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(bs); //{0, 2} so 0th index and 2nd index are set. 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs.toLongArray())); //prints [5]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs.toByteArray()));

        //Method_2          
        value = 42;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value)); //101010
        BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { value });
        System.out.println(bitSet);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bitSet.toLongArray())); // prints [42]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bitSet.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

**Q1)** What i didn't understand; which is correct approach (Method_1 or Method_2).
Method_1 seems to be correct one, but `bs.toLongArray()` gives different results.

**Q2)** Could you please explain this api `public static BitSet valueOf(long[] longs)` accepts array of long values instead of single long ..? And what does really doing with this array.

Java doc says the below; but i really didn't get the meaning.

> More precisely,  BitSet.valueOf(longs).get(n) == ((longs[n/64] &
>   (1L<<(n%64))) != 0)
>   for all n < 64 * longs.length.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bits are numbered from the right.

```
42 = 0b101010
       543210 <-- bit numbers
```

Hence output of `{1, 3, 5}`.

Your method #1 numbers bits from the left.

You also don't need to call `bs.clear(i)`, since a new [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet-int-) doesn't have any bits set.

> All bits are initially `false`.

---

As for how `BitSet.valueOf()` works, it's fairly simple.

There are two versions for `byte` data (`byte[]`, `ByteBuffer`), and two versions for `long` data (`long[]`, `LongBuffer`).

A `byte` consists of 8 bits, and a `long` consists of 64 bits. The `BitSet` will then be built with the first N (8 or 64) bits from the first value, the next N bits from the second value, and so forth.

E.g. if you call `BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { 1, 2, 3 })`, bits 0-63 come from first number, bits 64-127 comes from second number, and bits 128-191 comes from third number, resulting in `{0, 65, 128, 129}`.

If you call `BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 })`, bits 0-7 come from first number, bits 8-15 comes from second number, and bits 16-23 comes from third number, resulting in `{0, 9, 16, 17}`.